# Disable Docker Upon Startup in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker

I thought this was pretty straightforward to make docker daemon not to start when I start my machine, but seems not to be the case. I installed docker manually and then used the following simple line post installation:

```
sudo systemctl disable docker
```

But to my surprise this did not do much and I could still see the daemon happily running around!

```
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~$
```

Is there anything that I'm missing? Any clues?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This works for me (18.04):

```
$ sudo systemctl disable docker.service
$ sudo systemctl disable docker.socket
```

You can run:

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i docker
```

To check the docker services and disable them manually in the same way `$sudo systemctl disable <service-name>`.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#configure-docker-to-start-on-boot-with-systemd) `containerd.service` should also be disabled and not only `docker.service`. They don't mention `docker.socket` although I disabled all three.

Answer (score 11):

in ubuntu  Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

after

```
$sudo systemctl disable docker.service
$sudo systemctl disable docker.socket
```

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i 'state\|docker'
UNIT FILE                                  STATE           VENDOR PRESET
alsa-state.service                         static          enabled      
docker.service                             disabled        enabled      
docker.socket                              disabled        enabled
```

As pointed out by others you need:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

to have docker not working in the current session, check it with :

```
sudo systemctl docker
```

Answer (score 5):

`disable` will not stop the process by itself, it just won't start it the next time. You need to either restart your machine or type

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
```

to stop the process.

Comment: OP says prevent docker autostart. Disable would be needed in that case, right? Stop (as the name suggests) would only stop the process.

Comment: Yes. You need to disable the service to prevent the autostart

Comment: I just restarted my machine and I can see that dockerd is started after a restart which is what I want to avoid. Your post does not help!

Comment: run `systemctl status docker`. What do you see?

Answer (score 3):

Check docker services running

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i docker
```

Check the task names, usually docker.service and docker.socket on my system Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS they are named this way.

Prevent docker from starting using the listed docker tasks

```
sudo systemctl disable docker.service
sudo systemctl disable docker.socket
```